# Flutter Listview.builder, RangeError Index Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2. How do I fix?

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I have A listview.builder in all of my "Project Cells". I get the index from my list of classes and it gives me an error:

Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in
range 0..1, inclusive: 2.

For input string: "1,277"
For input string: "1,277"
For input string: "1,277"
For input string: "1,277"
For input string: "1,277"
For input string: "1,277"

...

```
class SchoolProject {
 final int index;
  final String name;
 final String about;
  final String subject;
 final String daysLeft;
 final List<User> projectMembers;
 final List<SchoolProjectTask> tasks;

  SchoolProject(this.index, this.name, this.about, this.subject,    

 this.daysLeft, this.projectMembers, this.tasks);
  }

  class User {
  final int index;
 final String username;
 final String description;
 final String school;

User(this.index, this.school, this.description, this.username);
  }

 var SchoolProjectOne = SchoolProject(
  0,
  "Historia Prov - Berlinmuren",
  "Läs in på Berlinmuren och kubrakrisen, hur usa mot soviet       
  skapade"
    "kalla kriget och hur kriget aldrig bröt ut för att folk var        

rädda!",
"History",
"2 Days",
[William],
[
  SchoolProjectTask(
      0,
      "Läs Om Berlinmuren",
      "",
      "2 Days",
      [William]
  ),

  SchoolProjectTask(
      1,
      "Ta reda på Kubakrisen",
      "",
      "2 Days",
      [William]
  ),

  SchoolProjectTask(
      2,
      "Kommunism vs Capitalism",
      "",
      "2 Days",
      [William]
    ),
  ]
 );

  Future<List<SchoolProject>> _getSchoolProject() async {
  var data = allSchoolProjects;
  print(data);
  return data;
  }


 Container(
 height: 50,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 12, top:5),

 child: FutureBuilder(
  future: _getSchoolProject(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  if(snapshot.data == null) {
   return Container(
     alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 2,
                     ),
               );
           }
           else return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
               itemCount: 
                  snapshot.data[index].projectMembers.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                 return Container(
                 margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                 child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFBA68C8),
                      child:   


   Text(snapshot.data[index].projectMembers[index].username[0],
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  ),
                      );
                      }
                    );
                   }
             ),
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the [index] i think will work.

itemCount: snapshot.data[index].projectMembers.length,

itemCount:         snapshot.data[index].projectMembers.length,

Comment: How do you mean? I need to return (projectMembers.length) for every cell. The problem Is that I can't display the name for every user in every circle avatar!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using the same variable `index` but there are to differents sets of `scopes` so you have 4 items in here:

> itemCount: snapshot.data[index].projectMembers.length,

But when you are using it later

> Text(snapshot.data[index].projectMembers[index].username[0],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),

For the username just have 1 `[william]` it will never exist index 2, so there i think you can do something like [this example](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List/asMap.html)

And inside you can create in return a Text Widget and add in there using a fat arrow function or an anonymous function by index as the example in the docs shown.

Comment: Thanks but how do I display every users username in every circular avatar?

Comment: Is it possible to add like a third parameter to the Listview.builder (Buildcontext context, int index, int userindex)?